# Provided toolbox icons not working

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, toolbox

I have provided the tool box icons for my control like the below,

```
[ToolboxBitmap(typeof(MyControl), "ToolBoxIcons.MyControl.bmp")]
public class MyControl : Control
```

Bitmap is placed in folder named **ToolBoxIcons** and Bitmap name is **MyControl.bmp** and the bitmap is added as a **Embedded resource**.

I have build my project and added the dll in tool box which choose items concept.

But the provided icon is not displaying.

Does any one know, why the icons are not displaying? Please update me on this.

Comment: Is it a 16x16 bitmap?

Comment: @Gareth -  yes it is